# A random number between $0$ and $1$ is chosen. What is the probability of $0$ not being among its digits?

Tags: probability

I wish I had work to show but I'm having trouble with this one.

When asked what's the probability of, say, the first digits being $3,1,4$ we can say it's $(\frac{1}{10})^{3}$. If asked for the probability of a given number not appearing in among the first x digits, then it's $(\frac{9}{10})^{x}$.

In this case it seems there are an infinite number of "sub intervals" that need to be ruled out, and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not clear.  How are you choosing the number?  Are you choosing a infinite string of digits?  And how are you defining the probability?  Usual would be to let $p(N)$ be the answer if you only choose $N$ digits, and then to let $N\to \infty$.  If this is what you mean, the answer is pretty clearly $0$.  As you point, this would get us to $\lim_{N\to \infty}.9^N=0$.

Comment: The exercise simply states "A random number in the interval [0,1] is chosen". It could be any real number between 0 and 1.

I just realized I could state that the probability of the number being irrational is 1, so the probability of it not having any zeroes is (1/10)*(1/10)*...  = 0. I guess it seems kind of flaky because I didn't prove that the probability of a random number chosen between 0 and 1 being rational is zero.

Comment: Yes, but with infinite sets you need to specify more...there is no uniform discrete measure on an infinite set.  But, I think the approach you took (and which I formalized a bit in my earlier comment) is fine.  Do you see why that gets you to the answer $0$?

Comment: Yes. If we accept that the number will be irrational with probability 1, then it's easy to see.

The "discrete" probability of any given number is 0, because the probability measure taken is P([a, b]) = b - a. The exercise didn't state that, but it was said in my class. I should have specified it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your "flaky" computations are precisely the point...and points to you for seeing that they are unpersuasive.  You need to spell out what mechanism you have in mind.

Comment: I think the limit argument is entirely persuasive.  That certainly has the property you want (exercise).  and it is clear that you can't avoid $0$ forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that "random number between $0$ and $1$" means random with respect to the uniform distribution, i.e., the probability that the random number is in a subinterval $[a,b]$ of $[0,1]$ is the length $b-a$ of the subinterval. Then your calculation of $(\frac9{10})^x$ is correct for the probability of having no $0$ in the first $x$ digits. The probability of having no $0$ at all is therefore $\leq(\frac9{10})^x$, because all the numbers with no $0$ at all are among the numbers with no $0$ in the first $x$ digits. And this is true for all natural numbers $x$.  Fortunately, the only non-negative number that is $\leq(\frac9{10})^x$ for all natural numbers $x$ is $0$. So we can conclude that the probability of getting no $0$'s at all is $0$.